# declare variable in stored procedure sql 2008

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, declare

I am working on a project which uses a stored procedure. When I try to use the stored procedure in the project, I'm getting this error:

```
The formal parameter "@Mode" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.
```

Please help me in solving this problem.

This is my stored procedure:

```
alter PROCEDURE [ITAssets_sp_IT_Assets]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    (@Mode varchar(12)='ADD',
    @ID integer , @AssetCode nvarchar(20)=null, @Description nvarchar(70)=null,
    @Site nvarchar(10)=null)
AS
Begin

    IF @Mode='ADD'
        Begin
  Begin Tran
      INSERT INTO [IT_Assets]
          ([ID]
                ,[AssetCode]
                ,[Description]
                ,[Site])
                    values
    (@ID, @AssetCode, @Description, @Site
    )
     If @@ERROR <> 0  
            ROLLBACK TRAN 
        Else
            COMMIT TRAN

    Select  @ID
End
ELSE 
Begin
        Begin Tran
                UPDATE [IT_Assets]
                    SET 
    AssetCode = @AssetCode, Description = @Description, Site = @Site 
    WHERE ID = @ID      
    If @@ERROR <> 0  
            ROLLBACK TRAN 
        Else
            COMMIT TRAN
        Select  @ID 
End
End
```

Am calling the stored procedure in below code:

```
Dim ht As New Hashtable

ht.Add("@Mode", "ADD")
ht.Add("@ID", txtID.Text)
ht.Add("@AssetCode", txtAssetCode.Text)
ht.Add("@Description", txtDescription)
ht.Add("@Site", ddlSite.SelectedValue.ToString())

AppExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "IT_Assets", , ht)
```

AppExecuteNonQuery code:

```
 Public Shared Function AppExecuteNonQuery(ByVal SQLCommandType As CommandType, ByVal Command As String, Optional ByVal ParamTable As Hashtable = Nothing, Optional ByRef OutputParamTable As Hashtable = Nothing, Optional ByVal UsePrimaryConnection As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal ConnName As String = "", Optional ByVal ConnString As String = "") As Integer
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Try
            If UsePrimaryConnection Then
                cmd = AppGetSQLCommand(SQLCommandType, Command, ParamTable, OutputParamTable, AppProperties.ConnectionString, True, UsePrimaryConnection, ConnName, ConnString)
            Else
                cmd = AppGetSQLCommand(SQLCommandType, Command, ParamTable, OutputParamTable, AppProperties.ConnectionString1, True, UsePrimaryConnection, ConnName, ConnString)
            End If

            Dim res As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

            For Each param As SqlParameter In cmd.Parameters
                If param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output Then
                    OutputParamTable(param.ParameterName) = param.Value
                End If
            Next

            Return res
        Finally
            If Not cmd Is Nothing Then
                If Not cmd.Connection Is Nothing Then
                    If cmd.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                        cmd.Connection.Close()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling the stored procedure?

Comment: @shree.pat18 question editted

Comment: And can you please share the code of `AppExecuteNonQuery` method too? The error seems to point to the statement calling your procedure to have issues.

Comment: It may be standardized, that doesn't mean it's not the source of the error. The error clearly indicates "the actual parameter passed in requested output" - so we need to see the code that generates the actual parameters.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever answer is editted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this in your code:

```
AppExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "IT_Assets", , ht)
```

Since `ht` is at position 4, it is getting assigned to `OutputParamTable` which adds `OUTPUT` parameters to the stored procedure. That's exactly what the error message says too.

To fix it, move it to position 3 i.e.

```
AppExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "IT_Assets", ht)
```

Comment: I got this error `No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.`

Comment: @7alhashmi - that's because you're adding `txtDescription` rather than `txtDescription.Text` as the `@Description` parameter.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks! I missed out on that.